# Call an External API from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to call an external API from AWS Lambda but it currently does not provide me anything, no errors or sign of the API request even being sent out. I am frankly not sure what is driving the cause of the issue. I have tried the following.

1. Change the permissions to allow for HTTP requests
2. Connected the Lambda Function to a VPC

Below is my code, please let me know if there is anything else I should be looking into.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

function findWordsInQuotations(sentence) {
    // Regular expression to match words within double quotations
    // This regex pattern captures words within double quotes
    const regex = /"([^"]+)"/g;

    // Use the match method to find all words in quotations
    const matches = sentence.match(regex);

    if (matches) {
        // Extract and print the words within quotations
        const wordsInQuotations = matches.map(match => match.replace(/"/g, '')); // Remove double quotes
        return wordsInQuotations;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

async function getReverseDictionary() {
    
    let apiKey = process.env.ChatGPT_API_KEY;
    const inputPhrase = "smart but evil";
    const inputType = "";
    const inputTone = "";

    // Use the OpenAI GPT-3 API to find a singular word
    let prompt = `What are the five best words for "${inputPhrase}", when you respond, just respond with the words, with the first letter capitalized and all of the words delimited by commas.`;

    if (inputType.trim() === "") {
        console.log("InputType is empty!");
    } else {
        prompt = prompt + 'For reference, this is for a ' + inputType;
    }

    if (inputTone.trim() === "") {
        console.log("InputTone is empty!");
    } else {
        prompt = prompt + '. For reference, I am going for a  ' + inputTone + ' tone.';
    }

    console.log(prompt);

    const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 
            messages: [
                {
                    role: 'system',
                    content: "You are a dictionary"
                },
                {
                    role: 'user',
                    content: prompt
                }
            ],
            max_tokens: 50, // Limit the response to one token (word)
        }), 
    });
    
    
    console.log(response);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('the CHATGPT RESPONSE:' + data);
    const chatGPToutput = data.choices[0].message.content;
    console.log(chatGPToutput);
    const singularWord = findWordsInQuotations(chatGPToutput);
        
    const wordsArray = chatGPToutput.split(',');
    console.log(wordsArray);

    let resultOne = wordsArray[0];
    let resultTwo = wordsArray[1];
    let resultThree = wordsArray[2];
    let resultFour = wordsArray[3];
    let resultFive = wordsArray[4];
    
    return resultFive;
}


export const handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  ;
  const response = {
    Result_One: getReverseDictionary(),
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

Comment: "Change the permissions to allow for HTTP requests" I'm not aware of any such permissions that you could assign to a Lambda function.  "Connected the Lambda Function to a VPC" Connecting the function to a VPC will generally block it from accessing anything outside the VPC, such as an external API. Connecting it to a VPC does not help this scenario in any way, it actually makes it much more difficult. You would have to deploy the function to private subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway if it needs to be in a VPC and still access external services.

Comment: Hopefully you're aware that Lambda functions emit logs to CloudWatch Logs. Review those logs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait till you get back the response from the external API.

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const data =  await getReverseDictionary();
  
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  return response;
};
```